# getvalue of check box on server side in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I am using GWT.
I have a `chkBox` and `fileupload` which are added to `formPanel`.

after formPanel.submit();

On Server Side

I want the value of `chkbox`

so

```
if (item.isFormField()) {
        if (item.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("chkbox")) {
                        chkbox= Streams.asString(item.openStream());
                    }

                }
```

when `chkbox.getvalue` is `true` , the value on server side is **On** and `chkbox.getValue` is `false`  the i get `null` on the server side.

i need the values of `chkbox` so that i can **perform operation on file depending on the value of** `chkbox`

Comment: The logical thing to do would be to pass the value up from the client as part of the request. IMO, the server should be agnostic of UI -- as far as the server should be concerned, the UI doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On" is the default value of a checkbox when no [*form value*](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#setFormValue%28java.lang.String%29) has been provided.

That value will only be sent to the server if the box is checked (absence of the field means it was unchecked): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/form-submission.html#constructing-form-data-set

If you *really* want to send anything else, then don't give your checkbox a *name* and instead use a [`Hidden`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hidden.html) field that you update using a `ValueChangeHandler` on the `Checkbox`.